# How to show that intersection of events is greater than the maximum of 0 and sum of Probability of events $-n+1$

Tags: probability, inequality

I am having trouble with showing this basic inequality and I would appreciate any tips on showing the following:

For a Probability space $(\Omega, A, P)$ and $A_1, \ldots, A_n \in A$ show that:
$$
P(\bigcap_{j=1} ^n A_j) \geq \max\{0, (\sum _{j=1} ^n P(A_j)) - n +1\}
$$

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Use De Morgan,

$$\bigcap A_i = \left(\bigcup A_i'\right)'$$

and then $P(A')=1-P(A)$.

Comment: Of course, thank you